# Cycles not rendering certain objects

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

As you cansee the little guns coming out of the wings do not show up in the render. The guns are the object named cylinder which has the render icon checked in the outliner. Why is this not showing up in the render (right picture)?

Comment: Post the blend file

Answer (score 1):

turns out the cylinder was not on the same layer. Having the object tab selected (two left of the modifier tab) I clicked on the top left layer and bam it was there :)